# $\epsilon - N$ definition of a limit of sequence problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

i have a question i cannot seem to solve! i would really appreciate help if possible. please explain how to solve this question from textbook, i really want to learn but i cant

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + n} = 0$$

so my attempt!

$$\frac{1}{n^2 + n} \lt \epsilon$$
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon} \lt n^2 + n$$
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon} \lt n \lt n+1 \lt n(n+1)$$

but now i don't know what to do

is this problem like the squeeze theorem now?

i need to get $n \gt N$ for that last inequality??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and we look for $N$ such that
$$\frac1{n^2+n}<\epsilon$$
whenever $n\ge N$. We have
$$\frac1{n^2+n}<\frac1n<\epsilon\iff n>\frac1\epsilon$$
so take $N=\lfloor \frac1\epsilon\rfloor+1$ and we have the desired result.

Comment: so we want to just get n out by itsself and then we can just rearrange for $\epsilon$ as long as the inequalities hold? what if we wanted to find the rangee of N that would work? or can only one N work? couldn't we then also get $\frac{1}{n^2} lt \epsilon \rightarrow n \gt sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$

Comment: @user137849 If one $N$ works, then all natural numbers greater than $N$ also work. So your first question in the comment above is equivalent to finding the smallest $N$ that works.

Comment: You need just one $N$ and of course try to find the easiest @user137849

Comment: what if I wanted the smallest N?

Comment: In this case you have to solve the quadratic înequality:
$$n^2+n>\frac1\epsilon$$@user137849

Comment: both your answer and the other answer on here are good, how do i decide the best answer???

Comment: yours because you responded multiple times and it has more upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Now since $\mathbb{R}$ is [arichimedean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property), your statement follows by choosing an  $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t  $N\epsilon> 1$. If $n>N$ then $\frac{1}{n^2+n}<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$ .

Comment: so $\frac{1}{\epsilon} \lt N$ we then use the floor function to minimise $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ on the natural numbers, then add 1 to make it equal to N to get what he said above: floor($\frac{1}{\epsilon}) + 1$

Comment: To check that the floor functions is a well defined function you basically have to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is archimedean.